# Git: how do I find tags pointing to specific revision?

Tags: git, git-tag

Given some revision, say `HEAD^^^`, I need to find tags pointing to it.

I can do that with `git show-ref --tags | grep $(git rev-parse $REV) | awk '{print $2}'`.

Is there special command for it? (That works on Windows too.) Maybe there is even back reference mechanism in Git...

Comment: Do you want to find a tag that comes somewhere *at or before* that commit, or a tag that points specifically *to* that commit?

Comment: Specifically to it.

Comment: Weird. I tried to search without word "pointing" and found nothing. Then added this word to heading but haven't googled with this word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

To list tags pointing to a given commit use the following command:

`git tag --points-at` *commit*

`git tag --contains` isn't a correct answer to this question, since it also includes later tags from which the specified revision is reachable.

---

```
git tag -l --contains $REV
```

From [**`git tag`** documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

> **`-l <pattern>, --list <pattern>`**
>
> List tags with names that match the given pattern (or all if no
>   pattern is given).
>
> **`--contains [<commit>]`**
>
> Only list tags which contain the specified commit (HEAD if not
>   specified).

Comment: It seems it answers my question. I'll check soon.

Comment: There is also `git tag --points-at`, available since Git 1.7.10, if that's what the OP wants.